# Explanation of the model used in the following glm commands

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, offset

In my textbook, the following two models were used. I understand the theory of glms, but I'm not too sure as to the specifics of the options and parameters you can play with in the R glm function. I would like to know what is the mathematical model behind these two glm functions.

```
vExposures = c(121.7, 893.1, 5079.3, 32546.7, 21155.9, 10606.7, 1751.5, 23.1)

vDeaths = c(3, 6, 48, 278, 510, 866, 363, 11) 

oModelOne = glm(vDeaths ∼ 1, offset=log(vExposures),
            family=poisson)
```

vExposures and vDeaths as above.

```
vAgeBand = factor(c(35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105))
oModelTwo = glm(vDeaths ∼ -1 + vAgeBand,
            offset=log(vExposures), family=poisson)
```

Specifically, I would like to know what the 1 does in the first code block and the -1 does in the second code block, and what the offset does.

In the simple Poisson regression model, I know that we model $\log(y)=\alpha+\beta x$. What is the model for these two code chunks. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you have $family=Poisson$, both models assume that $vDeaths$ follow a Poisson distribution.

The mathematical model of your first example is 
$$\log E[vDeaths]=\log (vExposures)+ c,$$
where $c$ is a constant to be estimated.

For your second example, it is
$$\log E[vDeaths]=\log (vExposures)+ \beta_x, $$
where $x$ is each age level: age 35,45,...,105.

In fact, your first model estimates a constant $c$ which is the average death rate across all ages. Your second model estimates a death rate for each age level (8 in total).

-1 means that there is no intercept and 1 there is an intercept. An offset is a covariate for which there is no related parameter to be estimated.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me what is the difference between omodel2 and stratifying, i.e. doing 8 separate models.

Comment: I edited my answer. I didn't check that $vAgeBand$ is a factor.